# Using edge features for GCN in DGL

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, graph-databases, chemistry

I'm trying to implement a graph convolutional network (GCN) in the Deep Graph Learning (DGL) package for Python. In many papers, edges have discrete features, and each possible value is associated with a different weight matrix or set of weight matrices. An example would be [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acscentsci.8b00507). Is anyone familiar with how to implement a model like this in DGL? The DGL team's example of GCNs for [graph classification](https://docs.dgl.ai/tutorials/basics/4_batch.html), as does [another example](https://iwatobipen.wordpress.com/2019/02/01/try-gcn-qspr-with-pytorch-based-graph-library-rdkit-pytorch-dgl/) I found online.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether the question still needs to be answered, but I guess it boils down to how to implement models like [R-GCN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06103) or [HGT](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01332) with DGL. Some of these layers come build-in with DGL [here](https://docs.dgl.ai/api/python/nn.html). But it is also easy to implement your own computations. The following explanation only makes sense if you know the basic computational process of DGL during a forward pass through a graph layer (message, reduce, apply_node), if not DGL has good tutorials on that as well. To extend the usual graph computation to for example edges of different types you need to create a heterogenous Graph object and call `multi_update_all` on that graph object. You can pass a dictionary to that function which specifies the computation per edge type.